# How to do Page Zoom Out(Control Minus Minus) in SeleniumBase

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, zooming, ui-automation, seleniumbase

I am using SeleniumBase for automating one of the UI pages. I want the code to do CONTROL MINUS MINUS so that the page zooms out automatically.

I have tried the below methods and its working fine, but after the zoom out my next line of code is failing as the driver is not able to find the element after the zoom out.

`driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='90%'")`

How do I zoom out in SeleniumBase without hindering the working scripts ?

Comment: Can you show that next line of code?

Comment: It looks like you already answered your own question, but if changing the zoom level makes elements harder to click, use the `self.js_click("SELECTOR")` method.